# Homeomorphism Between Spectra: Atiyah Macdonald Ch. 3 Ex. 21

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, localization, zariski-topology

I checked if anything on this questions exists on MSE, but I found nothing. I did find two solutions available via google, but was skeptical of both.

This is **Exercise 21 - i)** from Chapter 3 of *Introduction to Commutative Algebra* by M.F. Atiyah and I.G. Macdonald.

The exercise states:

> Let $A$ be a ring, $S$ be a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$, and $\phi \colon A \to S^{-1}A$ the canonical homomorphism. Show that $\phi^{*} \colon \mathrm{Spec}(S^{-1}A) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is a homeomorphism of $\mathrm{Spec}(S^{-1}A)$ onto its image in $X = \mathrm{Spec}(A)$. Let this image be denoted by $S^{-1}X$.

I am satisfied with 3/4'ths of my solution. Namely, we know that $\phi^{*}$ is continuous by **Exercise 21 - i, Chapter 1**. We also know this restriction mapping is surjective, trivially. Further $\phi^{*}$ is injective by applying **Exercise 20 - ii, Chapter 3** that every prime ideal of $S^{-1}A$ being an extended ideal is a sufficient condition for infectivity. We know the hypothesis that every prime ideal of $S^{-1}A$ is extended is satisfied since **Proposition 3.11 - iv)** gives a bijective correspondence, $\mathfrak{p} \longleftrightarrow S^{-1}\mathfrak{p},$ where $\mathfrak{p}$ are the prime ideals of $A$ that don't meet $S$ and $S^{-1}\mathfrak{p}$ represents $\mathfrak{p}^{e}$, thus every prime ideal in the localization is extended.

My issue is with the final step, showing that the inverse map is continuous. To be honest, I have been struggling to decided what precisely the rule defining the inverse function would be? I believe it is simply the action of $\phi$? I decided to follow the same outline for how this text had us show that $\phi^{*}$ it self was continuous, so here is the proof I came up with. I am very skeptical however as I don't believe I am using the follow power of my hypothesis:

Proof:
To show ${\phi^{*}}^{-1}$ is continuous we show ${\phi^{*-1}}^{-1}(X_{f}) = Y_{\phi^{-1}(f)}$, apologies for the atrocious notation on the left hand side, I simply mean the pullback of the open basis set $X_f$ in $\mathrm{Spec}(S^{-1}A)$ under the inverse of $\phi^{*}$. If successful this obviously satisfies the usual topological definition of continuity since $Y_{\phi^{-1}(f)}$ is open in $S^{-1}X \subseteq \mathrm{Spec}(A).$ The argument is

$$\mathfrak{p} \in {\phi^{*-1}}^{-1}(X_{f}) \iff \phi^{*-1}(\mathfrak{p})\in X_{f}$$
$$\iff \phi(\mathfrak{p}) \in X_{f}$$

but since $\mathfrak{p}$ is some contracted ideal, $\phi(\mathfrak{p})$ is just some $\mathfrak{q}$ in $S^{-1}X$, then

$$\iff f \notin \phi(\mathfrak{p})$$

$$\iff \phi^{-1}(f) \notin \mathfrak{p}$$

$$\iff \mathfrak{p} \in Y_{\phi^{-1}(f)}.$$

Comment: The plural of spectrum is spectra ;) https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373/why-are-words-ending-in-um-and-us-pluralized-to-end-in-a-and-i-resp

Comment: Also, how about showing that it's an open map instead of dealing with the inverse? Where do the distinguished open sets of $Spec(S^{-1}A)$ get mapped to? (I'm a little sleep deprived, I hope this is helpful.)

Comment: Thank your for the reference, I think I was avoiding the word spectra because I thought it had a meaning in a different branch of math. Does showing it's an open map imply the inverse is continuous? I have very little topology background.

Comment: Ah, I just checked Wikipedia, a continuous bijection is a homeomorphism iff it is open (or closed) map, so it suffices to just check $\phi^{*}$ has either property?

Comment: @PrinceM Yes that's correct

Comment: @PrinceM I'm pretty sure you can show a bijective map is open iff it's inverse is continuous! It follows from the definitions. Perhaps the advantage of this approach is more psychological than practical, but it seems to be helpful.

Comment: I understand what you mean about the psychological advantage, and yes after thinking about it, it is apparent why this condition would imply the inverse is continuous!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Y_g$ be some distinguished open set of $Spec(S^{-1}A)$. Then $g\in S^{-1}A$ so we can write $g=h/s$ for $h\in A$ and $s\in S$. But $s$ is a unit in $S^{-1}A$ so actually $Y_g=Y_{h/s}=Y_{h/1}$. Then, you can check that the image of $Y_{h/1}$ under $\phi^*$ is given by $X\cap X_h$, which is open in $X$. This shows that $\phi^*$ is an open map.

Comment: $X \cap X_{h} = X_{h}$, did you mean $S^{-1}X \cap X_{h}$?

Comment: And, although it seems entirely plausible, could you give me a quick reason behind why $S^{-1}X \cap X_{h}$ is open? I tried to express $S^{-1}X$ as an open set, my hunch was maybe that it is the complement of $V(S)?$

Comment: Wait, I'm dumb, are we considering $S^{-1}X$ with the subspace topology?

Comment: And I'm glad you posted this response because I probably don't have enough intuition yet to have spotted that X_h/s and X_h,1 are the same subsets... makes perfect sense in retroSPEC ;)

Comment: @PrinceM Yes, we are considering $S^{-1}X$ with the subspace topology (or else what?). Also, if you recall the definition of $X_f$, which is $X - V(f)$, then it easily follows that $X_{h/s} = X_{h/1}$. One direction is trivial; conversely, we want to show $h/1 \in p$ implies $h/s \in p$. Since $h/1 = h/s \cdot s/1$ where $s/1 \notin p$ (unit!), by primeness, it follows that $h/s \in p$.